# Would this Point Buy method be unbalanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, homebrew, ability-scores

I’m wanting to create a very unique character based around stat creation. The resulting character would be physically and mentally inept at all stats except one. Which stat is not the question but rather the method. Would this Point Buy method be unbalanced?

9=1, 10=2, 11=3, 12=4, 13=5, 14=7, 15=9, 16=11, 17=14, 18=17, 19=21, 20=25, 21=27 and -1 from another score.

Example stats before racial modifiers;

STR=8, DEX=21, CON=8, INT=7, WIS=8. CHA=8.

Max possible stat after racial modifiers is 23 and cannot be increased by ASI’s and without magic items.

The high stat would be able to be increased with the racial modifiers but it would max at an odd number. I am showing the Point Buy numbers to show how I came to the number selection and not just pulled it out of nowhere.

Comment: I'm somewhat confused here, is 9 the minimum and 21 the maximum? What is the total number of points to spend? Why is the gap between 20 and 21 smaller than the gap between 19 and 20?

Comment: Are you trying to create a balanced character using a point buy system, or are you trying to create a point buy system?

Comment: Because if you're asking if a starting character with a 21 in one ability and 7-8 in all the others is balanced, that sounds like the exact opposite of balanced.

Comment: Related: [bounded accuracy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/134248/23970), [bounded accuracy again](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/44826/23970), and [allowing scores above 20](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/130521/23970), all here on-site.

Comment: It seems you are hacking the point buy just to create a specific character concept. If that is the case, then instead of asking "is this custom point buy balanced?" it's better to ask "is this character concept with 21 8 8 8 8 7 stats balanced?" and provide information about that character. The latter question is better because it gets straight to the point, which means the answers will also get straight the point and be more useful.

Comment: @Medix2 All stats start at 8 but one would be increased to 21 but in doing so one of the others would be lowered by 1. The gap is smaller because it also adds a negative.

Comment: @MarkWells Your second comment is exactly what I'm asking. I see it is unbalanced.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes, it's unbalanced.

Allowing ability scores above 20, regardless of racial modifiers, is outside the scope of the average adventurer–only attainable through very specific magic items or high level class features. This point buy system would allow stats at that high tier at level 1, which is completely unbalanced.

It also seems like you're a player in this instance, not the DM. In that case, it's not even really your decision as to what point-buy, stat-rolling, or other systems for determining your stats are available to you, but your DM. Make sure to ask what is allowed in the game that they are running for you.